# Find the the row that has a different value from all other rows in a data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe, subset

In data.frame `f`, I'm wondering how to find the following (using BASE R):

For any `id` cluster in `f` that has `3` or more rows AND *has all the same row value* **except ONE**, find that ONE row value that is different in that `id` cluster?

In other words, only clusters with 3 or more rows *that* have all the same row value except ONE are the target not simply all clusters with 3 or more rows.

By `id` cluster, I mean as if we do: `split(f, f$id)`.

***Note:*** This is a toy example, a functional answer is appreciated (*the answer below is not updated!*).

```
f <- data.frame(id = c(rep("AA",4), rep("BB",3), rep("CC",3)), X = c(2,2,2,3,1,1,1,0,1,2), 
                                                               Y = c(5,8,8,8,6,3,1,6,1,1))
```

**Desired output:**

```
data.frame(id = c("AA", "AA", "CC"), value = c(3, 5, 6), var.name = c("X", "Y", "Y"))

#   id value var.name
# 1 AA     3        X   # HERE `3` on `X` is the ONE for `AA` cluster in `f`
# 2 AA     5        Y   # HERE `5` on `Y` is the ONE for `AA` cluster in `f`
# 3 CC     6        Y   # HERE `6` on `Y` is the ONE for `CC` cluster in `f`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `stack()` the data.frame and then subset using `ave()`, retaining cases where combinations of the ID and index variable have two distinct values and the combination of the value, group, and index is unique.

```
f_long <- cbind(f[1], stack(f[-1]))
f_long[with(f_long, ave(values, id, ind, values, FUN = length) == 1 &
      ave(values, id, ind, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == 2), ]

   id values ind
4  AA      3   X
11 AA      5   Y
18 CC      6   Y
```

Comment: @Reza - double check your expected output - the command doesn't match what's being printed currently.

Comment: Now, your solution doesn't consider that each data.frame must first have at least 3 rows! Try it on the following data where `BB` has two rows but your new solution shows `BB` in its output `f.new <- data.frame(id = c(rep("AA",4), rep("BB",2), rep("CC",3)), X = c(2,2,2,1,1,4,3,3,3), 
                Y = c(9,8,8,8,6,6,7,1,1))`

Comment: I made some changes to your solution and now it works! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following 4 lines can help you

```
fs <- split(f,f$id)
lst <- lapply(fs, function(v) apply(v[,-1],2,function(z) ifelse(length(table(z))==2, names(table(z))[table(z)==1],NA)))
r <- Filter(function(x) !is.na(x),unlist(lst))
data.frame(id = gsub("(.*?)\\..*","\\1",names(r)) , value = r, var.name = gsub(".*?\\.(.*?)","\\1",names(r)), row.names = seq_along(r))
```

***Details for each line***

```
### split f
fs <- split(f,f$id)

### get the list of the ONE
lst <- lapply(fs, function(v) apply(v[,-1],2,function(z) ifelse(length(table(z))==2, names(table(z))[table(z)==1],NA)))
# $AA
#   X   Y 
#  "3" "5" 
# 
# $BB
#   X  Y 
#   NA NA 
#
# $CC
#   X   Y 
#   NA "6" 


### filter out the NA in the list
r <- Filter(function(x) !is.na(x),unlist(lst))
# AA.X AA.Y CC.Y 
# "3"  "5"  "6"


### yield the final data frame
data.frame(id = gsub("(.*?)\\..*","\\1",names(r)) , value = r, var.name = gsub(".*?\\.(.*?)","\\1",names(r)), row.names = seq_along(r))
#   id value var.name
# 1 AA     3        X
# 2 AA     5        Y
# 3 CC     6        Y
```